# X ~ binomial distribution vs Y ~ negative binomial. Show that $P(X \leq r-1) = P(Y > n)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

$X$ has binomial $(n,p)$ distribution

$Y$ has negative binomial $(p,r)$ distribution

How to prove that $P(X \leq r-1) = P(Y > n)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the interpretations of the events in question. $(X\leq r-1)$ represents the event that in $n$ Bernoulli trials with success probability $p$, there were less than $r$ successes. That implies that for $r$ successes, we need more than $n$ such trials.

If $Y$ represents the number of trials it'd take to get $r$ successes, then the event $(X\leq r-1)$ would correspond to the event $(Y>n)$. The only caveat is that $Y$ would follow a negative binomial distribution with parameters $(r,1-p)$ instead of $(r,p)$.

Since the events correspond, their probabilities are equal.

Comment: thanks.  but are there a mathematical way to show the prove? can we use the PMF function to show above?

Comment: @azCats: It's quite cumbersome to prove algebraically. Even if you use CDF, you'll have to deal with resolving beta functions. Using the definition of the distributions themselves and equating the events in question seems like a non-tedious way to solve the problem.